# Code compliance of running EMT on exterior of exposed chimney inside

Tags: wiring, conduit, chimney, nec

I am working on a 1920s era home with an exposed brick chimney inside. The chimney is not connected to a fireplace but is used to vent the water heater and furnace in the basement. I am currently moving a light switch on the main floor and the best place for it to be would be the outside wall of the chimney. I am wondering if it is a violation to mount a run of EMT from the attic along the chimney and mount the switch to the side in a box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fine as long as you can properly mount it. Rock is not normally a smooth surface and a little hard to anchor to in a neat workmanlike manner.

Comment: I was thinking of using tapcons and EMT brackets. But am totally open to other suggestions.

Comment: Tapcons and single hole straps work well for EMT. You will need to use raintigh couplings and box ends or threaded adapters if u use a conduit body like a LR or RR to go through the wall and have a clean install. I usually use LB's and anchor to the wall but have used the brick in the past.

Comment: Do I need to use raintight couplings if it is all indoors? It's a strange exposed chimney running through the center of the house.